# suds fails in python3.8

Tags: suds, python-3.8

Currently im migration my automation code from python 2.7.9 to python 3.8.1 
We have many soap api's which use suds 0.4 version with python 2.7.9 and it works fine 
But after migrating to python 3.8.1 it fails 
I tried with suds-py3 library it continues to fail.

Below is the error i get

```
File "C:\Users\administrator\net.py", line 375, in __getattribute__
    if hasattr(attr, '__call__') and \
File "C:\Users\administrator\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 315, in __getattr__
    return getattr(port, name)
File "C:\Users\administrator\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 419, in __getattr__
return getattr(m, name)
File "C:\Users\administrator\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 510, in __getattr__
   return self[name]
File "C:\Users\administrator\venv\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 523, in __getitem__
    raise MethodNotFound(qn)
suds.MethodNotFound: Method not found: 'cessService.chargePort.__call__'
```

I have tried suds-jurko and suds3 libs but it still fails.

Is there a simple fix for it?

Currently switched back to 2.14 and continued.

Answer (score 0):

There no way to make suds work.

First tried to make changes in suds itself, where the suds calls failed due to python 3, I added if else so if python 3 do this else for python 2 do this, in this way i made little progress, but i ended up making lot of changes in core codes of many modules and it was becoming less desirable to add to our framework.

Switched to zeep, it took around 2-3 to understand and and was able to automate what was required. 
Zeep documentation is good to certain extent but not the best one, they have some mistakes in them.

But suds replacement we can currently use of Zeep